# Submenu is wordpress, doesn't stay static scrolls through the page

Tags: wordpress, scroll, frontend, submenu

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJYVj.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clr2C.png)

I tried to modify the settings in the page, couple of different lines of code. But nothing worked.
I wanted the submenu to open and be in full screen like this one https://www.glasgowcomedyfestival.com/ but it doesn't work. If I choose any other settings the menu doesn't appear how I would like it to be.